# Selecting a DOM element after The element is loaded after ajax

Tags: javascript

Assume I need to select `.my-class` But that is not yet in DOM elements It will load by ajax After complete dom loaded.

Now question is How can i get it work after it is loaded.

`var class = jQuery('.my-class');` It will not work if called in `document ready function`.

How can I get It selected??

> I don't want to touch ajax function.I want to do it from another js file

Comment: You want to bind events to DOM element after loading it via Ajax?

Comment: Yes but I don't want to touch ajax function.I want to do it from another js file

Answer (score 0):

Use parent selector, i.e.

```
body
```

or

```
document
```

In combination with jQuery.fn.on ( see: https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler)

But better to use closest parent selector, the one DOM element closest to your dynamic DOM element that won't be loaded dynamically, since that is most efficient.

```
$(parentSelector).on(event, childSelector, function(){
    // whatever you want to do
});
```

So code would be like:

```
$('.some-parent-class').on('click', '.my-class', function(){
    // whatever you want to do
});
```

Comment: Nice ! but in case of selecting a class within this code?? `$('.some-parent-class').on('click', '.my-class', function(){
    jQuery('.class-two').addClass('three');
});`              It does not work.Here `class-two` is also new

Comment: You can add any child class, no matter of depth `$('.some-parent-class').on('click', '.my-class, .three', function(){
    // whatever you want to do
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple setInterval script to poll for your target selector.

```
var timer = setInterval(timerFunc, 500);

function timerFunc() {
    if ($('.my-class').length){
      clearInterval(timer);
      console.log('exists');
    }
}
```